# If i prompt and input from the user 3 times i.e, lets say a number. Can i check automatically if the user inputted the-same number all 3 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance,

```
    demo_list = [] #This is just to display all inputs from the user at the end
    c=0

    while c<3:
        answer = input("Please enter a number ") # User types 1 all three times for instance
        demo_list.append(answer)
        c+=1

    print(demo_list)  # Should print this.. check below

    # [1,1,1]
```

Is the a way for python to check and see if all the inputs from the user were all the same value?

In this case all the values were the same '1' but can I do a check in the background without printing out what the user inputted?

Comment: Do a for loop through the values and compare them all to `demo_list[0]`

Comment: Check whether there are *three __unique__ values* in the list. `set` deduplicates lists. The `len` of a `set` tells you how many unique values are in it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need to check if all the elements of `demo_list` are identical. You can do this by comparing the number of occurences of the first element with the length of the list. This will need you to use the [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) and the [`list.count()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm) functions.

```
demo_list = [] 
c=0
while c<3:
    answer = input("Please enter a number ")
    demo_list.append(answer)
    c += 1

# Begin logic to check whether all inputs are equal
all_equal = False
if demo_list.count(demo_list[0]) == len(demo_list):
    all_equal = True

# Use value of `all_equal` in your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all values in the list are the same.

```
if all([demo_list[0] == a for a in demo_list]):
    print("All are equal.")
else:
    print("Different.")
```